# Map json array to typescript object array with constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, class-transformer

So I have a json array like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "This is the first title",
    "image": "img/first_img.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "This one is the second",
    "image": "img/second_img.png"
  }
]
```

My goal is to map the simple json array to typescript object array, which is defined as follows.

```
export class GenericField {
  public Required: boolean;
  public Disabled: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.Required = false;
    this.Disabled = false;
  }
}

export class StringField extends GenericField {
  private readonly _minLength: number | null;
  private readonly _maxLength: number | null;
  private readonly _value: string;

  constructor(
    minLength: number | null,
    maxLength: number | null,
    value: string
  ) {
    super();
    this._minLength = minLength;
    this._maxLength = maxLength;
    this._value = value;
  }
// ...
}

export class UrlField extends GenericField {
  private _url: string;

  constructor(url: string) {
    super();
    this._url = url;
  }

  public get Url(): string {
    return this._url;
  }
}

export class SliderObject {
  public title: StringField;
  public image: UrlField;

  constructor(title: string, image: string) {
    this.title = new StringField(null, null, title);
    this.image = new UrlField(image);
    this.image.Disabled = true;
  }
}
```

When I map with `class-transformer`, the objects aren't mapped correctly. How do I achieve that I can access `Required` field and `Disabled` field, which is not present in json.

**Stackblitz**

[See my StackBlitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-utev16?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.ts)

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (nor a _"json Object array"_)

Comment: Are you looking for automapper in TS like [this](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/getting-started/overview)?

Comment: _"So I have a json array like this:"_ - No, you don't. That's an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like the following (assuming `response.data` is where the JSON text is).

```
const items: Array<{title: string, image: string}> = JSON.parse(response.data)

const sliderObjects = items.map(item =>
    new SliderObject(item['title'], item['image']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with your own reviver and conventions in your models to support proper deserialization.

```
class SliderObject {
  public title: StringField;
  public image: UrlField;

  constructor(title: string, image: string) { /* class initialization */ }

  static fromJSON(data: { image: string; title: string; }): SliderObject {
    return new SliderObject(data.title, data.image);
  }
  static isDeserializableFromJSON(data: any): data is { image: string; title: string; } {
    return data && typeof(data.image) === 'string' && typeof(data.title) === 'string';
  }
}

function jsonReviver(_: string, value: unknown): unknown {
  if (SliderObject.isDeserializableFromJSON(value)) {
    return SliderObject.fromJSON(value);
  }
  return value;
}

console.log(JSON.parse(`[/* array data */]`, jsonReviver));
```

In the example above I have added to static methods to SliderObject to help with serialization and a custom json reviver function.  The static methods detect if data create from **JSON.parse** can be used to create a sliderObject and the other actually creates the new class.  The reviver will call the guard method and return a SliderObject if the guard passed.

There are lots ways to skin this cat.  I personally eschew TypeScript classes in favor of interfaces which I find are more flexible.  Why try to make TypeScript C# or Java?  By using interfaces, I can largely avoid situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

Please check some updates that I made in order to have your object attributes accessible:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-w5b97l?file=src/app/field-definition.ts

A few notes:

- The `GET` request from the `slider_object.json` file is **NOT** returning an `Observable<SliderObject[]>` but an `Observable<SliderObjectDTO[]>` (or some other name for the interface).
  An instance of `SliderObject` has the `StringField` attribute and the `UrlField` attribute, while what you are reading from the file are JSON objects (**NOT** `SliderObject` instances) which check the `SliderObjectDTO` interface, so they will have the `title` and `image` properties.
- observables should follow this naming convention: `observableName$`, so with a `$` symbol at the end, thus `sliderObjects` renamed to `sliderObjects$`
- class attributes should not start with a capital letter, thus `Required` renamed to `required`, `Disabled` renamed to `disabled`. The same thing applies for the properties (getters)